# Angular 8: Reactive form field stop async call if the previous value is same as the current value

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a reactive form input field to enter name also the field have a async validator to check if the entered name is already exits in the database or not and once the form is submitted it will go in edit mode now the problem is once the form goes in edit and if we refresh the page or if we clear the name and enter the same name again, the form again send a async request to check the name and i want to stop it.

Now there are a lot of dirty way to stop the async call even i can handle it on the sever side but i don't want send a extra request to the server if the entered name is same as the previous name

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import { CompanyInformation } from 'src/app/data/models/company/company-Information.model';
import { CompanyApiService } from '../../service/company-api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-information',
  templateUrl: './company-information.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-information.component.css'],
  providers: [CompanyApiService]
})
export class CompanyInformationComponent implements OnInit {
  companyInfo: CompanyInformation;
  companyInfoForm: FormGroup;
  isEdit: boolean = false;

constructor(private apiService: CompanyApiService,private modalService: NgbModal) { }

ngOnInit() {
  //Call these function when the page load
  this.createCompanyInfoForm(); //Create company information reactive form
}

//Create company information form
createCompanyInfoForm() {
  this.companyInfoForm = new FormGroup({
  'companyName': new FormControl(null, {
    validators: [Validators.required],
    updateOn: 'blur',
    asyncValidators: this.checkDuplicateCompany.bind(this)
    }),
  })
}

//Check duplicate company name
checkDuplicateCompany(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
 const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.apiService.checkDuplicateCompany(control.value)
    .subscribe((data: BaseEntityModel<CompanyInformation>) => {
      if (data.status === 1) {
        //Return resolve
        resolve({ 'duplicateCompany': true });
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    }, err => {
      //Show error toast message
      this.msgService.showToastMessage('error', err.statusText);
    });
 });
 return promise;
}

//Save
saveComInfo() {
 //Call the API if in save mode
 if (!this.isEdit) {
  //If form is valid
  if (this.companyInfoForm.valid) {
    //Insert all form data to CompanyInformation model
    this.companyInfo = new CompanyInformation(this.companyInfoForm.value);
    //Set companyId if available
    this.companyInfo.companyID = this.datashareService.getCompanyId;
    //Call the service
    this.apiService.saveCompany(this.companyInfo)
      .subscribe((data: BaseEntityModel<CompanyInformation>) => {
         //If save success
         if (data.status === 0) {
           if (data.entity.length > 0) {
           this.datashareService.setCompanyId(data.entity[0]);
         }
          //Change the edit flag value
          this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
          //Disable the form
          this.companyInfoForm.disable();
        } else {
           //Show error message
           this.msgService.showToastMessage('error', data.message);
        }
    }, (err: any) => {
      //Show error message
      this.msgService.showToastMessage('error', err.statusText)
    });
  } else {
    //Mark all fields as touched to display validation
    this.companyInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();       
  }
} else { // If edit in edit mode
   //Change the edit flag value
   this.isEdit = !this.isEdit;
   //Enable the form
   this.companyInfoForm.enable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the company, and how you determine whether the form is in create mode or edit mode

Comment: @KurtHamilton Updated the question please check and i have flag to check if the form is in edit mode or in save mode

Comment: And just to be clear, you don't want to run the validator at all when the form is in edit mode?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I want to run the validator only if a user enter a different name, but if a user clear the input field and enter the same name again at this time i don't want to run the validator.

Comment: So you need to store the "original" data somewhere rather than relying on the data in the form. Do you store that anywhere at the moment? If so, can you show how you do that.

Comment: I don't save the original data anywhere and i got your point to save the original data and to check the original data with current data before sending the request but is there any easiest way to do it like an rxjs operator to check before sending a request or something. I tried distinctuntilchanged but it seems not working

Comment: This is a state problem that can't be magically fixed by RxJS. Also - is there a reason you're wrapping your observable in a promise? There shouldn't be any need for that? The trick here is to take control over when you make requests - that involves some kind of state-informed decision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212834/discussion-between-c-das-and-kurt-hamilton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you bind asyncValidators as per mode, let's say a variable mode has switch 'add'/'edit'. mode can be replace by 'edit' once form is submitted.

```
let mode = 'add'; //initialize with 'add' then switch to edit after submit.
createCompanyInfoForm() {
  this.companyInfoForm = new FormGroup({
  'companyName': new FormControl(null, {
    validators: [Validators.required],
    updateOn: 'blur',
    asyncValidators: this.mode == 'add' ? this.checkDuplicateCompany.bind(this) : call_different_method_to_bind
    }),
  })
}
```

Comment: I need to call the async function 'checkDuplicateCompany' in edit mode also only if a user enter a different name but sometimes  a user can clear the name field and enter the same name again at that time i don't want to make a call to server